# vba timer available in modules

Tags: vba, timer

Could anyone please tell me if and how it is possible to count time of running various modules in VBA excel?
I am only able to count the elapsed time of one single module. However, when it comes to more than 1 module it seems there is no info out there. Or I am blind.

With one module I pass Timer value to a variable set at the begining of code and then at the end. Then I deduct second variable from the first.
When I try to do it between modules initial variable value is reset to empty.

Many thanks for any pointers
Tommeck37

Comment: We can't tell what you are doing wrong if we don't see how you are doing it.

Comment: When you paste your code into the question, also include details letting us know whether the modules are standard code modules, or whether they are workbook or worksheet or form code modules.

Comment: Thank you YowE3K 1. Your questions pointed me to the answer. I got it.

Comment: I declared a Global variable outside all procedures and it worked good. cheers

Answer (score 1):

For a simple way to measure the time it takes to execute portions of your code, you can use the VBA timer() function. That function isn't perfect, but it's a good place to start.

Timer() returns the number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight, including fractions.

Just before you call a module, assign the result of timer() to a variable. Timer returns a Double, but you could store it in a variant, too. Then do another call to timer() just after the module. For example:

```
time1 = timer()
call Proc1()
time2 = timer()
call Proc2()
time3 = timer()
debug.print "Proc1 time: " & cStr(time2-time1)
debug.print "Proc2 time: " & cStr(time3-time2)
```

There are other timers that you can use in VBA, but they require using windows procedures, and are harder to setup and use. For gross timing, this works fine. If you want to time with millisecond accuracy (or better), then look into other ways.